Count the amount of splits within a cell
OK I am after a VBA Function that will tell me how many splits would be required within a cell based on split character length and the closest split value of COMMA
OK, I have a cell (A33) as such,
N2NP002,N3NP001,N4NP027,N5NP012,N6NP003,N10NP010,Z401,Z217,Z218,Z219,Z220,Z2,Z22,Z223,Z224,Z225,Z226,Z227,Z228,Z229,Z230,Z231,Z232,Z233,Z234,Z235,Z236,Z33,Z237,Z238,Z239,Z240,Z241,Z222,Z223,Z224,Z225,Z226,Z227,Z228,Z229,Z23
This splits into 3 cells based on the following criteria, split at comma maintaining a length as close to 76 characters.
I have a routine that splits this as follows,
N2NP002,N3NP001,N4NP027,N5NP012,N6NP003,N10NP010,Z401,Z217,Z218,Z219,Z220,Z2  (Which is 76 Characters)   

Z22,Z223,Z224,Z225,Z226,Z227,Z228,Z229,Z230,Z231,Z232,Z233,Z234,Z235,Z236                (73 Characters)   

Z33,Z237,Z238,Z239,Z240,Z241,Z222,Z223,Z224,Z225,Z226,Z227,Z228,Z229,Z23                (72 Characters)   

What I want is a VBA function that will tell me that 3 cells will be required for my split routine.
ie  =SplitNumber(A33,76) where A33 is the input text, 76 would be the character length and to split at a COMMA.
So in the example given I would like to see the result of =SplitNumber(A33,76) as 3
Remember the catch here is that when the 77th character is a comma, then the split happens at character 76.
ie So look for last comma at or before character 77 and then that value -1 is were you would split, as per the 1st split happening a Z2, where the comma is in position 77. If Z2 was Z12, Z12 would be pushed into the next row and the flow on effect would be that SplitNumber(A33,76) would result in 4.
Example result of what my routine will give when Z2 becomes Z12,
N2NP002,N3NP001,N4NP027,N5NP012,N6NP003,N10NP010,Z401,Z217,Z218,Z219,Z220                 (73 Characters)   

Z12,Z22,Z223,Z224,Z225,Z226,Z227,Z228,Z229,Z230,Z231,Z232,Z233,Z234,Z235                 (72 Characters)   

Z236,Z33,Z237,Z238,Z239,Z240,Z241,Z222,Z223,Z224,Z225,Z226,Z227,Z228,Z229                 (73 Characters)   

Z23                 (3 Characters)
If interested, or if it helps, here is the Sub that I have to split A33 into 76 character lengths putting the result into cell C33, C34, C35 etc as required
Sub SplitTextBy76Chars() 

    Dim inputText As String 
    Dim maxLen As Integer 
    Dim result As String 
    Dim lastComma As Integer
    Dim cellRow As Integer 
    Dim checkChar As String      

    ' Read the input text from A33
    inputText = Range("A33").Value
    maxLen = 76 ' Maximum length for each split 
    cellRow = 33 ' Starting row for output, adjust as needed 
  
    Do While Len(inputText) > 0 
        ' Get the first maxLen characters
        result = Left(inputText, maxLen)          

        ' Check if the 77th character is a comma
        If Len(inputText) > maxLen Then
            checkChar = Mid(inputText, maxLen + 1, 1) 

            If checkChar = "," Then 
                ' If the 77th character is a comma, use the first 76 characters
                result = Left(inputText, maxLen)
                inputText = Mid(inputText, maxLen + 2)
            Else 
                ' Find the last comma within this substring
                lastComma = InStrRev(result, ",") 
                ' If a comma is found, split there; otherwise, take the full 76 characters
                If lastComma > 0 Then
                    result = Left(result, lastComma - 1) 
                    inputText = Mid(inputText, lastComma + 1) 
                Else 
                    inputText = Mid(inputText, maxLen + 1) 
                End If 

            End If 
        Else 
            inputText = "" 
        End If         

        ' Write the result to the next row 
        Range("C" & cellRow).Value = result
        cellRow = cellRow + 1 

    Loop 
End Sub


What result do you want if there are, for example, a string of 80 characters without a comma?

Hi Chronocidal, the longest a string of characters between commas would be 11, so that event does not occur  :)

If you only need the count:
Public Function SplitNumber(txt, maxLen As Long)
    Dim el, s As String, col As New Collection, v As String, tooLong As Boolean
    For Each el In Split(txt, ",")
        v = s & "," & el
        tooLong = Len(v) > maxLen
        If tooLong Then col.Add s
        s = IIf(tooLong, el, v)
    Next el
    If Len(s) > 0 Then col.Add s
    SplitNumber = col.Count
End Function


Use absolute cell reference (e.g. $B$4), click to cell address in formula and press F4 to change to absolute reference:
Public Function SplitNumber(inputText As Range, Optional maxLen As Integer = 76)
    Dim x As Integer, dic As Object, splVal, dkey
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    x = 1
    For Each splVal In Split(inputText.Value, ",")
        If dic.Exists(x) Then
            If Len(dic(x) & "," & splVal) <= maxLen Then
                dic(x) = dic(x) & "," & splVal
            Else
                x = x + 1
                dic.Add x, splVal
            End If
        Else
            dic.Add x, splVal
        End If
    Next splVal
    x = Application.Caller.Row - inputText.Row + 1
    If dic.Exists(x) Then
        SplitNumber = dic(x)
    Else
        SplitNumber = dic.Count
    End If
End Function

Past the formula and parameters, then press enter and drag the formula down (or copy).
test:


I replaced the delimiters at the split points with a different delimiter ("|"), then created an array using the new delimiter. Next, I used the WorksheetFunction.TRANSPOSE() to spill the data over as many rows as needed.
I also added the SplitNumber() function for completeness.

Function SplitNumber(Text As String, ChunkLength As Long) As Long
    Dim Result As Variant
    Result = SplitIntoDelimitedChunksByLength(Text, 76, ",")
    SplitNumber = UBound(Result) + 1 - LBound(Result)
End Function

Function SplitIntoDelimitedChunksByLength(Text As String, ChunkLength As Long, Optional Delimiter As String = ",", Optional TempDelimiter As String = "|")
    Dim n As Long
    Dim StartOfChunk As Long
    Dim Length As Long
    Dim LastTempDelimiterPosition As Long
    Dim NextDelimiterPosition As Long
    n = 1
    
    Do While InStr(n, Text, Delimiter) > 0
        n = InStr(n, Text, Delimiter)
        LastTempDelimiterPosition = InStrRev(Text, TempDelimiter, n)
        NextDelimiterPosition = InStr(n, Text, Delimiter)
        If (n - LastTempDelimiterPosition = ChunkLength) Or (NextDelimiterPosition - LastTempDelimiterPosition + 1 >= ChunkLength) Then
            Mid(Text, n, 1) = TempDelimiter
        End If
        n = n + 1
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    SplitIntoDelimitedChunksByLength = Split(Text, TempDelimiter)
End Function

